# Restoring nuget package culture specific

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, tfsbuild, culture, nuget-package-restore

I have problem getting a version of a nuget package with culture specific resource file in it on a build machine (TFS 2015 Build)

On my desktop (Win7 & Vs2015U3, both in fr-CA), when I restore, for instance, the package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client", it comes with a "lib\net45\fr" folder which contains the file "System.Net.Http.Formatting.resources.dll".

However, on my build machine (same thing, Win7 & VS2015U3 both in fr-CA), when the build agent restores the package through the VS solution build task, it doesn't contains the "\fr" in it. Thus, the resource file is missing.

Any idea what could be the cause of this behavior ?

Comment: Found it. I was mixing the package folder in "C:\Users\tfsbuild\.nuget\packages" and the package folder in the solution.  When the package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" is restored from the cloud it is cached into the "C:\Users\tfsbuild\.nuget\packages" folder. Without the "lib\net45\fr" folder.  But when restored into the solution packages folder, the "lib\net45\fr" folder is present. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.fr is already present in my package.config file.

Comment: since you have resolved this issue, if possible, please post your solution as an answer and mark it, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue as yours to find the answer easy. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: It is partially explained, locally on my dev machine (which the OS and the IDE are in french). But not resolved since the problem is on my build machine. The build agent doesn't seems to consider correctly the language of the OS nor the IDE installed (on the build machine). Both are in french. The localized dll "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.fr" is not restored in the workspace even though it is specified in the package.config file.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you restored the package through the VS build task. So I assume you checked **Restore NuGet Packages** in VS build task.

Please notice, **Restore NuGet Packages** option in VS build task is deprecated. 
Make sure to clear this checkbox and instead use the [NuGet Installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer) build step.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will update my build definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.fr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client.fr) package to your project and then check in the changes.

Comment: It is already present in the package.config file. See my answer above.